# Problems when using scanf with %i to capture date (mm dd yyyy)

Tags: c, date, printf, scanf

I'm writing a program that calculates the number of elapsed days between two dates. To do this, I have to input the dates as integers in a structure defined like so:

```
struct date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
```

Now, I've figured out how to run my program, but it's really bugging me that the user can't input a date in (mm dd yyyy) format when the month or day are single digits. Let me show you my code (please don't mind the debug printf statements):

```
printf("Enter your start date (mm dd yyyy)\n");
scanf("%i %i %i", &startDate.month, &startDate.day, &startDate.year);
// DEBUG printf("Start date = %i/%i/%i\n", startDate.month, startDate.day, startDate.year);
// DEBUG printf("start date month = %i", startDate.month);

printf("Enter your end date (mm dd yyyy)\n");
scanf("%i %i %i", &endDate.month, &endDate.day, &endDate.year);
// DEBUG printf("End date = %i/%i/%i\n", endDate.month, endDate.day, endDate.year);
```

If the user enters:

```
08 08 2004
```

Then the start date is recorded as

```
0/8/0
```

Which is equal to the first three digits entered by the user. OK, I understand that. I also understand that the user can just enter "8 8 2004" and the program runs fine...but I believe programming is about details and this one is a bugger. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: If you try the input `8 25 2004` does it work? Also, try replacing the `%i`s with `%d`s.

Comment: I think you would be better off reading the input in as a string, and use something like getdate() or strptime() to parse the string to your desired representation. Also, you can look into more advanced libraries to offload this work from you. Furthermore, I advice against the use of scanf() to do user input - too many things can go wrong with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `%i` conversion specifier causes [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) to parse the input as if `strtol()` was called with `0` as the base argument. So, since `08` begins with a `0`, and `8` is not an `x` or `X`, it treats the `08` as an octal sequence. But, since `8` is not a valid octal number, it stops there, and the result is `0` for the first number.

The second number then gets the `8`, as it is delimited by whitespace. The white space is skipped, and the third number is parsing `08` as octal again, resulting in `0` for the third number. The remaining `8` and the year `2004` are not parsed.

Use `%d` to parse decimal digits.

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &startDate.month, &startDate.day, &startDate.year);
```

As mentioned in the comments, [`scanf()` should generally be avoided](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). As an alternative, you could use `fgets()` to retrieve an entire line of input first, and use `sscanf()` to do parsing. This allows for better error recovery, since an error can be diagnosed by the line that caused the error, and the line can be gracefully skipped as well. `scanf()` is meant for structured input, and can only give you a rough idea of where a scanning error occurred. And, errors cause the input to jam, leading to confusing debugging sessions at times.

Comment: Well that just spawned an hour of research. Thanks for showing me the light on scanf.