# C scanf behaving unexpectedly with %i to scan dates

Tags: c, scanf

For some reason, when I run my program it is not giving me the option to type numbers for the statements associated with day1 and year2. Why is it doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void ) {

    int day1, day2, month1, month2, year1, year2;

    printf("Enter date 1 mm\n");
    scanf("%i", &month1);

    printf("Enter date 1 dd\n");
    scanf("%i", &day1);

    printf("Enter date 1 yyyy\n");
    scanf("%i", &year1);

    printf("Enter date 2 mm\n");
    scanf("%i", &month2);

    printf("Enter date 2 dd\n");
    scanf("%i", &day2);

    printf("Enter date 2 yyyy\n");
    scanf("%i", &year2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you entering the numbers?

Comment: ^ By running the code, typing the numbers, and hitting enter.

Comment: I mean in what format. Give examples.

Comment: Works for me... [test](http://pastebin.com/GueLDVmF)

Comment: This problem is likely related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16473705/315052).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you typing `08` or `09` for the first `mm` value?

If so, that's the trouble: the `%i` conversion specification accepts 0x before a hex value, and 0 before an octal value (see the POSIX specification for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html)).  If you type `08` or `09`, only the zero is valid as octal, so it leaves the 8 or 9 in the input, which is immediately read as the `day1` value.  Similarly, you probably enter `08` or `09` for `day2`, and the same failure occurs so `day2` contains 0 and `year2` contains 8 or 9.

You could help yourself, and everyone else, by:

1. Checking that the `scanf()` calls are successful.
2. Printing the values that are entered from within the program.
3. Including a transcript of the program running.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void ) {

    int day1, day2, month1, month2, year1, year2;

    printf("Enter date 1 mm\n");
    scanf("%i", &month1);

    printf("Enter date 1 dd\n");
    scanf("%i", &day1);

    printf("Enter date 1 yyyy\n");
    scanf("%i", &year1);

    printf("Enter date 2 mm\n");
    scanf("%i", &month2);

    printf("Enter date 2 dd\n");
    scanf("%i", &day2);

    printf("Enter date 2 yyyy\n");
    scanf("%i", &year2);

    printf("%.4d-%.2d-%.2d to %.4d-%.2d-%.2d\n",
           year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./date1
Enter date 1 mm
08
Enter date 1 dd
Enter date 1 yyyy
1999
Enter date 2 mm
12
Enter date 2 dd
09
Enter date 2 yyyy
1999-00-08 to 0009-12-00
$
```

The code doesn't check the `scanf()` calls, but it does illustrate the behaviour you saw.

#### Fix

If you want the numbers to be decimal even with leading zeroes, use `%d` instead of `%i`.

Only the hardiest C programmers enter dates in octal or hex.

Comment: I was actually entering 08 as the month. Problem solved.

Answer (score -3):

You need `%d` to take an `int` in as **d**ecimal digits.

```
scanf("%d", &year2);
```

Comment: Looks like `%i` should be fine: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: %i is also fine in C89.

Comment: You're right, but for the wrong reason. Both `%i` and `%d` are valid; the problem is that `%i` accepts octal input, so `08` or `09` is invalid. See [Jonathan Leffler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29442076/827263). (Note that for `printf`, `%i` and `%d` are equivalent.)

Comment: 4 downvotes for the right answer..sheesh

Comment: @MattMcNabb: The answer does not actually address the asked question of why `%i` is causing the behavior observed by the asker. It would have helped, though, if the question included the attempted input values.